# C++ - Constructing wrapper class around structure with same syntax as structure

Tags: c++, templates, structure, wrapper, aggregate-initialization

This is a follow-up to my previous question:
[C++ - Constructing wrapper class with same syntax as wrapped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882466/c-constructing-wrapper-class-with-same-syntax-as-wrapped-data)

Basically, I'm trying to make a wrapper template around some data, and construct / set the wrapper with the same syntax as the data.

If I use something like a struct, I can achieve that with forwarding the parameters so the syntax can be:

```
struct SomeStruct{

    int a, b, c;

    SomeStruct(int _a, int _b, int _c) {/*...*/}

};

// ...

WrapperClass<SomeStruct> wrapped_struct1{1,2,3};
WrapperClass<SomeStruct> wrapped_struct2 = {1,2,3};
WrapperClass<SomeStruct> wrapped_struct3( 1,2,3);
```

The problem is that this only works if I have that constructor defined in the struct. Can I make it work without having to define it?

The wrapper currently looks like this:

```
template<typename T> class WrapperClass{
public:
    T data;    
    template <typename...Args>
    WrapperClass(Args&&...args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) instead. Then

> If T is an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed.

e.g.

```
template <typename...Args>
WrapperClass(Args&&...args) : data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
//                                ^                           ^
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to / can keep both constructors or is the list-initialization one enough?

Comment: @Newline You can't, they can't be overloaded with same signature. You have to select one, note that for some cases effect might be different; e.g. for `std::vector`, `(10, 42)` would construct a `vector` containing 10 elements with value `42`; `{10, 42}` would construct a `vector` containing 2 elements with value `10` and `42`. You might also apply SFINAE or template specialization to perform dispatch.

Comment: Now it is all good except that copy-constructor and assignment is not working. It gives an error saying "cannot convert ‘WrapperClass<SomeStruct>’ to ‘int’ in initialization", and points to the list-init function:S. Even if I explicitly define the copy-ctor.

Comment: @Newline See [Why is template constructor preferred to copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57909923/3309790)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to understand how to do that same thing with variadic templates. How to stop that function from being called when "Args" is "WrapperClass<T>", but don't know how. Maybe I will have to ask another question:)